# Proof of Lorentz(seconde grade) cone is convex and self-dual

Tags: convex-geometry, dual-cone

Given Lorentz cone $L^{n+1}=\{(x,t)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}: ||x||_2 \leq t\}$

How can i proof the convexity and self duality? I tried to do it from definitions, but i couldn't solve it. Do i need more for the proof?

Comment: Well.. Convexity follows directly from the definition and the triangle inequality.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't see that, i made it way too complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\|y\|_2\le s$, $s\ge0$. Then 
$$
(x,y) + st \ge -\|x\|_2\|y\|_2 +st \ge0 \quad \forall \|x\|_2\le t,
$$
hence $(y,s)$ in the dual cone of $L^{n+1}$. Conversely, let $(y,s)$ be in the dual cone. Then
$$
(x,y)+st \ge 0\quad \forall \|x\|_2\le t.
$$
Setting $x=-y$, $t=\|y\|$, shows $-\|y\|_2^2 + s\|y\|_2 \ge0$, hence $s\ge \|y\|_2$. This shows $(y,s)\in L^{n+1}$.

Comment: In the first inequality why are the norms with a negative sign? Apart from that, this made it clear. Thanks.

Comment: It is Cauchy Schwarz reversed: $|(x,y)|\le\|x\|\cdot \|y\|$ implies $(x,y) \ge -\|x\|\cdot\|y\|$.